# Autoincrementation of numbers in textfield

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield

*Hello all*

I am generating an application in which I am having `4 fields ( product id, product name, product price, product description)`.

Now I want that the product id would be **generated automatically when I save my data**, i.e. when I run my app the text field of product id should be generated automatically and when I click on save button this id should be incremented by one and the id of last data should be saved.

So kindly help me out.

Comment: where r u saving the data?

Comment: `NSInteger productId = [productIDTextField.text integerValue]; productId ++; productIDTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", productId];`

Comment: @manujmv m saving data in the sqlite database..

Comment: @neilco these are 2 different statments seperated by semi colon or single only????.

Comment: @Sahil Three statements separated by semi-colons.

Comment: @neilco and where it should be written??

Comment: try with NSUserdefault. it is very simple ....

Comment: @manujmv the below example is not helping me out...

Comment: @Kalpesh how in which manner can u please give me code??

Comment: @manujmv read my question very carefully, it is  i want to increment the product id before saving the data, it should be incremented by itself. hope now u got my point.

Comment: @SahilDhiman: you can get the maximum product_id from my example. now u just add 1 to this id and when u save data to database, you should use this id as product_id

Answer (score 0):

try this way....

```
//fetch the MAX id
[self databaseOpen];
NSString *cc=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Select MAX(ProductID) from Table"];
NSMutableArray *temp=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
temp=[[database executeQuery:cc]mutableCopy];
[database close];
```

**Explaination** I am fetching the Maximum product_id from database Table.

```
int Product_id;
if (temp.count!=0 && ([[temp objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"MAX(ProductID)"] !=[NSNull null]))
    Product_id=[[[temp objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"MAX(ProductID)"]intValue]+1;
else
    Product_id=1;
//fetch the MAX id
```

**Explaination** If there is no record in the Table then Product_id=1
                 else It will incremented by 1;

```
  Txt_productID.text=[NSString stringwithFormat:@"%d",Product_id];
```

**Explaination** Print the Product_id in the Text Field

```
[self databaseOpen];
NSString *q=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Insert into Table (NAme,Price,Description) values ('%@','%@','%@')",txt_name.text,txt_price.text,txt_des.text];
    [database executeNonQuery:q];
    [database close];
```

**Explaination** Save the new Record in database.

Comment: Let me know if you have any problem.

Comment: I write the explanation under each code part. Let me know if you still need more explanation.

Comment: bro u are not getting my question, i want to increment the product id before saving the data, it should be incremented by itself. hope now u got my point.

Comment: I did the same thing. First increment the Product_id by 1 & then in the last I try to save data.

Answer (score 0):

You have to take a look on this tutorials

http://upadhyayajayiphone.blogspot.in/2012/11/insert-record-in-sqlite-table-get.html

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_SQLite_based_iOS_4_iPhone_Application

It contains all the operations for you. While you fetching data use `SELECT MAX(product_id) from TABLE_NAME` to fetch the last data.

Answer (score 0):

**If u want to achive  by  NSUserDefaults, then use following code**

```
// get total count   
int count=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]integerForKey:@"TotalIdCount"];


// on save button click increment count by one and stored it
count=count+1;
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults ] setInteger:count forKey:@"TotalIdCount"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Comment: what is totalIdCount??

Comment: TotalIdCount is key .

Comment: For more detail read this documentation carefully https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html